# Looping an invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell, scripting, sendgrid

I'm trying to automate a process at work which involves hitting SendGrid's API. For a short explanation.. with SendGrid you have Subusers and underneath those Teammates. There is no ready option to search all teammates, so you have to supply a subuser then display all teammates underneath. Rinse, repeat down the line. Well I'd like to automated as best as I can.

So the idea is to collect a teammate email address from then user then dump into a variable all the subusers then loop through those subusers looking for the $email variable.

I've never actually used loops in my scripts over the years so it's new territory for me and combining it with an invoke-restmethod just boggles me.  Heres what I've got so far:

```
$token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
#First uri is to pull a list of subusers
$uri = "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/subusers"
#Prompts for target email address
$email = Read-Host "Enter the users email"

$headers1 = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token"}
$headers2 = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $token" 
    "on-behalf-of" = "$subuser"
}
$subs = Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -uri $uri -headers $headers1
$subarray = $subs | select-object username


foreach ($su in $subarray){
    $teamarray = invoke-restmethod -method get -uri "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/teammates?limit=500&offset=0" -headers $headers2
    #$teamarray.gettype()
}
```

The last line is commented out.. I was trying to find the type of the `$teamarray` data but it's giving this error for each loop through the subusers:

```
invoke-restmethod : {"errors":[{"field":null,"message":"authorization required"}]}
At line:18 char:18
+ ... teamarray = invoke-restmethod -method get -uri "https://api.sendgrid. ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], 
    WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodComma 
   nd
```

This should mean the invoke-restmethod is malformed somehow. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something but when you define `$headers2` you use the variable `$subuser` but I do not see that defined anywhere.  Do you mean to get the `$subuser` from your `$subarray`?  If so, move the definition of `$headers2` inside your loop above the `invoke-restmethod` line and replace `"on-behalf-of" = $su.username` (don't need quotes around lone variables)

Comment: So nice, thank you! I have no idea how to make this as an answer but it def it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at using [Invoke-WebRequest vs. Invoke-RestMethod](https://superuser.com/questions/1235349/what-is-the-difference-between-invoke-webrequest-and-invoke-restmethod#1235561). I've found I prefer Invoke-WebRequest because I get to see more of the results instead of having them spoon fed to me which makes it easier to perform debugging.

Comment: Defintely interesting I'll say that. I'm not sure Im comfortable reinventing my wheel just yet. But I see what you mean with that link..